# Matlab Integral with passing in a constant variable.

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I have the following code, trying to integrate a function f with respect to the variable t, but needing to accept the parameter cfb (which has to be calculated beforehand).  How do I pass in cfb via the int() function?

`f = @(t) (cfb.*t)`

...
`cfb = %Something`

`d = integral(f, 0, upperLimit)`

How do I change this code so that f can take both t (from integral) and cfb as parameters?  I tried just changing it so `f=@(t,cfb)` and `integral(f(cfb)...`, but that just resulted in an error that f wasn't taking in enough parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea of using an anonymous function is good. Just define `cfb` **before** that.

```
cfb = %Something
f = @(t) (cfb.*t)
d = integral(f, 0, upperLimit)
```